# jquery upload and view image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I found a jquery to script that lets you preview an image before you upload it.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>
 function readURL(input) {
        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();            
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                $('#target').attr('src', e.target.result);
            }

            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }

    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>jQuery Uploads</h1>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <input type="file" id="imgInp" />
        <img id="target" src="#" alt="your image" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

I found it on jsfiddle and it works fine. But now i try to run it on my server and it doesn't work. I can't seem to figure out why its not working. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: That code as-is will not run because the element doesn't exist when you try to bind a change event to it.

Comment: jsfiddle runs JS in an onload handler by default. Move your whole script element to the end of the body (just before the closing `</body>` tag) and it'll probably fix it.

Answer (score 3):

I couple different things could be happening here.  My first guess would be that there is a timing issue of when the javascript is loading.  Try throwing your jQuery listener into a the "ready" call.

```
function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        var reader = new FileReader();            
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $('#target').attr('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
$(function(){
    $("#imgInp").change(function(){
        readURL(this);
    });
})
```

Also - make sure your protocol (http vs https) is matching your pull from code.jquery.com